# Почему генератор читает не все числа из файла?

Tags: python, генераторы

Допустим дан такой текстовый файл 26-39.txt:

```
5 28
1
2
3
4
```

Код:

```py
f = open('26-39.txt')
n, m = map(int, f.readline().split())
a = [int(x) for x in f]
```

Почему генератор, который формирует список а, не читает первую строку с двумя числами? Потому что как только эти два числа были считаны в n и m, они пропали из f?

Comment: `f.readline()` прочитала первую строку и переместила позицию чтения из файла на вторую. Первая строка не будет обработана в `for x in f`.

Comment: C чего Вы решили что не читает, в `m` и `n` находятся соответственно 5 и 28

Comment: и это не генератор

Comment: А если бы в формировании читалась первая строка, то вы бы получили ValueError